# Receive Querystring and Redirect page

Tags: php, redirect, query-string

How can I get a QueryString named "code" and redirect my page including the querystring?
**Example-**

I'll receive **mydomain.com/inteface.php?code=103103**

I need redirect for **mydomain_new.com/interface.php?code=103103.**

I know C#, but in this case I will need this code in php for redirect in a different server.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the superglobals called `$_GET` & `$_SERVER`. You can use `$_GET['code']` to grab the `code` variable from the current URL and `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to grab the domain like this:

```
        //Grab code from URL
        $code = $_GET['code'];

        //Grab current Domain Name being used
        $currentURL = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

        //Old Domain Name
        $oldDomain = "mydomain.com";


        //Read the header of the URL to test $domain is TRUE and $code has data
        if ($currentURL == $oldDomain && isset($code)) {

                 //Redirect to new domain using $_GET
                 header('Location: http://mydomain_new.com/interface.php?code=$code');//No need to concatenate single variable

        }
```

See:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: @EdilsonRafael No worries and glad it's working for you!

Answer (score 1):

```
header('Location:mydomain_new.com/interface.php?code='.$_GET['code']);
```